Adjust Pivot table depending on data on previous sheet
I Have a template already created in excel, the idea is to have a first sheet with data, and a second sheet with a pivot table.
The first sheet is generated from C# and returns a fixed list of columns but the rows are dynamics depending on some filters the user can choose.
My question is, how the pivot table can be refreshed automatically on the second tab depending on the rows returned on the first one?
In fact I'm not sure it's possible, but I'm not good on excel :)

I believe I found a solution, using OpenXML looks like it's possible

It is definitely possible. If you want the PivotTable to automatically include the newly added rows after refresh then you will have to ensure that the data in the first sheet is in the form of a Table and the PivotTable is based on that Table.

And if you are talking about Auto refreshing a PivotTable then there are two ways that I can think of. These two ways with the above suggestion will help you achieve what you want.
1. VBA:
'~~> Replace PivotTable1 with the name of your PivotTable
PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

VBA will also help you if you want to refresh PivotTable at regular intervals. You can use Application.OnTime with the above code to achieve that
2. PivotTable Option:
Right-click on the PivotTable and select PivotTable Options”. Then in the dialog, go to the Data tab and then check the box Refresh data when opening the file. This will automatically refresh the PivotTable on File opening.

